# async js chunks that include scss imports cause => Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: webpack, extract-text-plugin

There seems to be some issue when importing a scss file in a common chunk if that common chunk also imports an async/dynamic js chunk which imports another scss file.

```
//===== a.js =====
import './common';

//===== b.js =====
import './common';

//===== common.js =====
import 'es6-promise/auto';
import './common.scss';
// dynamic import
import ('./async.js');

//===== async.js =====
import './async.scss'
```

error with above file setup

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 3d99482…:52)
    at Object.95 (async.scss:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 3d99482…:52)
    at Object.96 (async.scss?eb60:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 3d99482…:52)
    at Object.94 (0.cb65e0.chunk.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 3d99482…:52)
```

**I opened an issue with full details and steps to replicate**

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/456